# Why is value NOT undefined for function parameter when executed by time driven trigger in Google Script?

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script

my time driven function in Google Apps Script is:

```js
    function addTopRow(d){

      if(d == "undefined"){ //when ran from time trigger
        var dT = (new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));
        d = new Date(dT);
      }
      else{
        d = new Date(d+"T00:00:00-08:00");
      }

      var row = [];
      var sheet_db = // DEFINE workbook SHEET here
      row.push(d);
      sheet_db.getRange("A3").setValues([row]);
    }

    //run same above function without any trigger, on & when required 
    function testInsertDate("2019-11-10");
```

**Usage Cases**
1. On time-driven Trigger every day around 1am. `d` will be UNDEFINED; so set `d` manually to today's date.
2. If called by any other function in sheet with `d` as date string. D will be defined this time.

**Expected Behaviour**
In Case 1, d is undefined, so function is using today's date.
In Case 2, d is defined/passed, so function should use that date.

**What's Happening**
Case 2 is working as expected. 
In Case 1, Date is always being taken as UNIX EPOCH (0) & upon adding the Timezone -8:00 sets it to Dec 31, 1969 always. Expected output is today's date.

**Question**
Why 'd' is NOT undefined in time driven trigger?
Is there any documentation/reference which lists all the parameters passed to a function WHEN it is time driven?

**Update**
I found the link on API for teh object getting passed: [Time-driven events @ https://developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question partially with my findings, but will wait for other answers too.

After using many Logger.log()s & Execution Summaries, I found that when this function is triggered by a time-driven trigger, `d` is coming out as an Object with the following value:

```
    {
        "authMode": {},
        "week-of-year": 47,
        "day-of-week": 7,
        "month": 11,
        "hour": 1,
        "year": 2019,
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "day-of-month": 24,
        "triggerUid": "2594419",
     ...)
```

Clearly the `...` part implies that there are more keys & values Logger.log() decided to truncate.

So, I updated the following `if` condition to check for typeof `string` instead of undefined:

```js
    //Previous Line:
    if(d == "undefined"){ //when ran from time trigger

    //Changed To:
    if(typeof d != "string"){ //when ran from time trigger
```

& its working now.